# Why green text go to the next line after space?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a chat app. When I receive the message not problem. but when I send the message after the space character text go to the next line.
If I write a combination while sending the message, it is not a problem, but if I leave a space between each word, it writes one under the other.

[I want to like fist text which is the how are you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4mAJ.png)

This is my html code

```
 <div class="container">

            <div id="chat-cont" class="clearfix">

            </div>
           

            <div class="row"><h5>Connection ID : <span id="connectionId"></span></h5></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7"><input type="text" id="sender" value="@ViewBag.message"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7"><input type="text" placeholder="ReceiverId" id="client"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7"> <input type="text" id="txtMessage"> <button>Send</button></div>
            </div>


        </div>
```

This is my js code

```
$("button").click(() => {
        let message = $("#txtMessage").val();
        var user = $("#sender").val();
        connection.invoke("ClientSendMessage", $("#client").val(),user, message)
            .catch(error => console.log("Error." + error));       
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.textContent = message;
        div.style.fontSize = "20px";
        div.style.fontFamily = "Josefin Sans, sans-serif";
        div.style.paddingLeft = "5px";
        div.style.paddingRight = "5px";
        div.style.paddingBottom = "3px";
        div.style.paddingTop = "3px";
        div.style.marginLeft = "500px";
        
        div.style.marginBottom = "2px";
        div.style.width = "fit-content";
        
        div.style.marginRight = "550px";
        div.style.float = "right";
        div.style.content = "";
        div.style.clear = "both";
        
        div.style.height = "fit-content";
        div.style.backgroundColor = "#056162";
        div.style.color = "white";
        
        div.style.borderRadius = "10px";
        div.style.border = "1px solid black";
        document.getElementById("chat-cont").appendChild(div);
        
    });

    connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
        var msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
        var encodedMsg =  msg;
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.textContent = encodedMsg;
        div.style.fontSize = "20px";
        div.style.fontFamily = "Josefin Sans, sans-serif";
        div.style.paddingLeft = "5px";
        div.style.paddingRight = "5px";
        div.style.paddingBottom = "3px";
        div.style.paddingTop = "3px";
        div.style.marginLeft = "0px";
        div.style.float = "left";
        div.style.content = "";
        div.style.clear = "both";
        div.style.marginBottom = "2px";
        div.style.width = "fit-content";
        div.style.height = "fit-content";
        div.style.backgroundColor = "#262D31";
        div.style.color = "white";
        div.style.borderRadius = "10px";
        div.style.border = "1px solid black";
        document.getElementById("chat-cont").appendChild(div);
        
    });
```

Comment: `div.style.marginLeft = "500px";` <-- the culrpit

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you very much I fixed but I wondered how did you understand the mistake?

Comment: F12 + check CSS. its by experience really.